# Multiple local strategies and isAuthenticated

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have 2 different strategies 'login' and 'adminlogin':

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
      failureRedirect : '/login', 
      failureFlash : true 
  }), function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('/');
  });

app.post('/adminlogin', passport.authenticate('adminlogin', {
      failureRedirect : '/adminlogin', 
      failureFlash : true 
  }), function(req, res) {          
      res.redirect('/admin');
  });
```

adminlogin is defined as:

```
assport.use('adminlogin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'uname',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, uname, password, done) {

    process.nextTick(function() {

        findAdminByUserName(uname, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { 
              console.log("1- ERROR::adminlogin: ", err);
              return done(err); 
            }

            if (!user) { 
              return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Unknown Admin: ' + uname)); 
            }

            // Now we do the comparison
            CUtil.comparePasswords(password, user.password, user.salt, function (err, isMatch) {            
                if (err) {
                  console.log("2- ERROR::adminlogin: ", err);
                  return done(err, null);
                }
                if (!isMatch) { 
                  return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage','Invalid admin or password')); 
                } 
                return done(null, cleanAdminUser(user));
            });
        });
    });}));
```

With the additional following code:

```
function cleanAdminUser(pAdmin) {

if (!pAdmin)
  return null;

var newAdmin = {
  _id: pAdmin._id,
  fname: pAdmin.fname,
  lname: pAdmin.lname,
  uname: pAdmin.uname,
  role: 'admin',
};
return newAdmin;}

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user._id);});
```

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

```
findById(id, function (err, user) {
  done(err, user);
});});
```

The problem I am having is that when a non-admin user logs in, is authenticated, and finally redirected to the user dashboard the session is maintained. Bit with adminlogin the session is lost.

Admin before redirect:

```
{ instance: 
   Authenticator {
     _key: 'passport',
     _strategies: { session: [Object], login: [Object], adminlogin: [Object] },
     _serializers: [ [Function] ],
     _deserializers: [ [Function] ],
     _infoTransformers: [],
     _framework: 
      { initialize: [Function: initialize],
        authenticate: [Function: authenticate] },
     _userProperty: 'user',
     _sm: SessionManager { _key: 'passport', _serializeUser: [Function: bound ] },
     Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
     Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
     Strategy: { [Function: Strategy] Strategy: [Circular] },
     strategies: { SessionStrategy: [Object] } },
  ***session: { user: 59f3c0d7f75cc7ef38733644 }*** }
```

Admin after redirect (in `isAuthenticated()`):

```
{ instance: 
   Authenticator {
     _key: 'passport',
     _strategies: { session: [Object], login: [Object], adminlogin: [Object] },
     _serializers: [ [Function] ],
     _deserializers: [ [Function] ],
     _infoTransformers: [],
     _framework: 
      { initialize: [Function: initialize],
        authenticate: [Function: authenticate] },
     _userProperty: 'user',
     _sm: SessionManager { _key: 'passport', _serializeUser: [Function: bound ] },
     Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
     Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
     Strategy: { [Function: Strategy] Strategy: [Circular] },
     strategies: { SessionStrategy: [Object] } },
  ***session: {}*** }
```

The code for isAuthenticated:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req._passport);         
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        return next(); 
    }   
    //Passport.authenticate('adminlogin', {session: false})(req, res, next);
    //res.redirect('/login');
    res.send({loggedOut:true});}
```

How can I check in `isAuthenticated()` a user that used `adminlogin`, since the default behavior is only checking for `login`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the application structure should be:

```
/app1
--/index.html as well as config.js & controllers.js
/app2
--/index.html as well as config.js & controllers.js
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!  Can you elaborate a bit more on the logic of your answer, and not just provide the code?

Comment: Basically I wanted to have a way to create multiple applications for multiple user types. What I had to do was to create different local strategies for different roles (user types). That was the easy pat. The hard part, and that was due to my lack of complete understanding of Angular was how to create separate applications based on separate roles. with angular its in fact very easy, as I learned. I created separate file structures for each role (user || admin) with each having their own config.js and controllers.js but a common app.js, services.js and directives.js.